# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm getting an error in a web page of mine as follows:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noConflict' of undefined"

I'm using jQuery in my page and it was suggested to me that I should use

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Is there a way I can unsure I don't receive the undefined error when setting my $j variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error has occurred, jquery is not loaded in your html. Add this in your header area `<sript src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js'>`

Comment: This mean that jQuery is not loaded in the web page, are you loading it?

Comment: Something is weird here, because if `jQuery` were simply not defined, the error would be `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. The error which FRed gets apperas like the `jQuery` variable is declared but its value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

I Faced the same problem.

Please Use the code like this.

Click Here

```
(function($) {

    $('#dev').click(function(){
        alert();/*You can add any code here */

    });

    })(jQuery);
```

If you want to Use .noconflict comment I will edit this.

Comment: This was awesome, passing jQuery object like this resolved conflict.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer saved me.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are currently not loaded jQuery into your html page. So your html looks like this after jQuery is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- load jQuery in header area -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- content -->

    <script>

      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

      console.log($j); // function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```